# How to create a .txt file in visual studio C# windows forms

Tags: winforms

I am using Visual studio windows form with C# and currently have the functionality to write order details to a existing .txt file using the following code;

```
System.IO.File.WriteAllText(@"C:\Visual Prototype\savedOrder.txt", text);
```

I am wanting a method of being able to create a new .txt file dynamically so that when a user selects to print the order details for OrderID: 121 a new .txt is created called savedOrderID121. Could someone please tell me a method of doing this as I am currently only able to save to txt files I have already created.

If it helps I store the selected Order ID in a variable called orderID so I guess the code would resemble(I have made up the method name);

```
system.createFile("savedOrderID" + orderID + ".txt");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually you have answered yourself, but just in case it will go like this:

```
System.IO.File.WriteAllText(@"C:\Visual Prototype\savedOrder" + orderID + ".txt", text);
```

Comment: Ah yes silly me, I thought I did exactly the same as the above but It didnt work. Now it does, thanks. Should I delete this question?